# Converting a list to a sequence to make a sympy Polygon

Tags: python, list, sequence, sympy

I would like to make a sympy Polygon from a list of points. The documentation says it takes a sequence of Points. I can't figure out how to convert.

```
from sympy import Point2D, Polygon

# this works
p1 = Polygon(Point2D(0,0), Point2D(1,0), Point2D(1,1), Point2D(0,1))
print(p1.area)

# this fails at the Polygon call
points=[]
points.append(Point2D(0,0))
points.append(Point2D(0,1))
points.append(Point2D(1,1))
points.append(Point2D(1,0))
t = tuple(points)
p = Polygon(t)
```

When it fails, I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t_polygon.py", line 14, in <module>
    p = Polygon(t)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Lib\site-packages\sympy\geometry\polygon.py", line 126, in __new__
    vertices = [Point(a, dim=2, **kwargs) for a in args]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Lib\site-packages\sympy\geometry\polygon.py", line 126, in <listcomp>
    vertices = [Point(a, dim=2, **kwargs) for a in args]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Lib\site-packages\sympy\geometry\point.py", line 157, in __new__
    raise ValueError('Nonzero coordinates cannot be removed.')
ValueError: Nonzero coordinates cannot be removed.
```

Comment: Try `p = Polygon(*t)`

Comment: Yes! Also, I can skip the call to `tuple()`, a direct `p = Polygon(*points)` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
t = tuple(points)
p = Polygon(t)
```

You need to write:

```
t = tuple(points)
p = Polygon(*t)
```

Comment: I did not know that `*` was the unpack operator. Now I am wiser.